# What is the intellij idea keyboard shortcut to list all other shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse has very good discoverability in that there is a keyboard shortcut thats lists all the keyboard shortcuts. On a Mac this would be Cmd+Shift+L, so on a pc I imagine this would Ctrl+Shift+L.

Is there an IntelliJ idea keyboard that achieves the same thing??

(... so that I can learn by doing, as I am working)

By the way, I am using 12.1.4 community edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Help` | `Find Action` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac) to see all the actions and their shortcuts.

There is no fast way to perform the reverse search yet, but you can open `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Keymap` and use the filter by shortcut to find the corresponding action. There is also a [feature request to make it easier](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99850), feel free to vote.

Comment: Also have a look at the intellij keymap (pdf ?) - i used to keep it on my desk and learn one more shortcut each day. And there is a plugin called key promoter which, in a slightly annoyng way, also helps u learn them.